# Using * with :not in css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Im working on a html linter using css.

Reference: https://bitsofco.de/linting-html-using-css/

I like the idea of highlighting elements that have inline styles like so:

```
*[style] {
    color: red !important;
    border: 5px solid red !important; 
}
```

However, I do have certain instances where I have to use inline styles, ie canvas elements.

1. How do I use the :not selector with the *?
2. Can I have multiple :nots, ie :not(canvas):not(form), etc

Comment: You sure *[style]:not(canvas) doesn't work?

Comment: I stand corrected. *[style]:not(canvas) DOES work. Must have checked it before the sass finished compiling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have works and excludes the canvas. And yes, you can chain multiple `:not()`s like that.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
*[style]:not(canvas):not(form) {
    color: red !important;
    border: 5px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<canvas style="foo">canvas</canvas>
<form style="foo">form</form>
<div style="foo">div</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

the :not() rule matches anything not matching the subrule. The subrule is a valid css selector. writing `[canvas]` will match any element with a canvas attribute, so this isn't what you want.

The correct usage is:

`*[style]:not(canvas):not(form)`